# Extend a controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have installed Codeigniter on IIS. Everything is going great.

I am trying to extend the CI_Controller class.  The reason I am doing this is to put a security check in the constructor.  Some controllers will extend the CI_Controller.  Some controllers, which need to be secure will extend MY_Controller.  This seems like a good approach to me.

So far I have followed these instructions:

[Creating Core Classes](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

But when I call a page which extends MY_Controller I get a blank page.
Check the network tab in Firebug, I see “500 internal server error.”
I check my CI logs I see this:

```
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 10:26:47 --> Language Class Initialized
```

Now, for a normal point of reference, when I load any controller which does not extend MY_Controller I see this:

```
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Session Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Helper loaded: string_helper
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Session routines successfully run
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> File loaded: application/views/user/session_box.php
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> File loaded: application/views/public/public_menu.php
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> File loaded: application/views/public/welcome_message.php
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> File loaded: application/views/template.php
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2014-11-24 11:00:14 --> Total execution time: 0.2295
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

**MY_Controller**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

    public static function &get_instance()
    {
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

**The controller which extends it:**

```
class Project extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();        
            $this->load->model('user_model');
        }

    public function index()
    {
            var_dump("hi");
        }


}
```

Comment: Firstly, was everything working before you extended the controller? Secondly, could you show the code for your `MY_Controller` class and and the controller that extends it... not all of it just the top part. Lastly, does the file name match the class name exactly (case-sensitive)?

Comment: Okay Ross, I have added my code

Comment: To respond to your questions: Every controller which does not extend MY_Controller works well.  MY_Controller.php file name matches the Controller name of "MY_Controller" perfectly including case.

Comment: @GRY, just to exclude one concern, you have  $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'; defined in application/config/config.php (?)

Comment: @EduardUta Yes sir. I have defined the subclass prefix in config as "MY_"

Comment: @GRY, can you change protected static $instance; and retry(in MY_Controller class)?

Comment: Can you clarify "Change" ?  Change it's name, it's value or it's usage?  I tried changing it's state to public and protected. It was initially private.

Comment: Just for the sake of ruling things out, which folder have you put it in?

Comment: ...also, are there any errors in you PHP error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your MY_Controller to:

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

This is because `$this` will already contain the instance as it is extending `CI_Controller`

I can't be certain this is the issue but I hope it helps!

Comment: I've just tested the code and it doesn't throw an error with `private static $instance;` or the method...it still isn't need though :)